# Radio Buttons in a popover

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, radio-button, popover

Hi everyone i need help with a problem.

I have now a functional popover in a modal that shows me how many keys i have. i need to ad radio buttons in the popover that controlls the key status ( 1 2 3 ) is this possible?

This is the popover:

```
<button type="button" id="example" 
class="btn btn-default" data-container="body" 
data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" 
data-content="Till detta skåp finns två nycklar." 
data-original-title="Nyckelstatus">
<img src="/resources/key_accept.png" />
</button>
```

This is in the viewmodel:

```
 $('#example').popover();
```

Thanks for all the help i can get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i fixed my own problem but thanks Nimmi for looking in to it :D

```
<button type="button" id="example" class="btn btn-default" data-container="body"
data-html="true"
data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right"
data-content="Till detta skåp finns två nycklar.
&lt;div id='constcon-options-form' class='form-horizontal'&gt;
&lt;input type='radio' name='keys' value='1' bind-value='key'&gt;
1  &lt;br&gt;
&lt;input type='radio' name='keys' value='2' bind-value='key'&gt;
2  &lt;br&gt;
&lt;input type='radio' name='keys' value='3' bind-value='key'&gt;
3  &lt;/div&gt;"
data-original-title="Nyckelstatus">
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can place your code inside of content like this :

```
$('#example').popover({content:'YOUR HTML RADIO BUTTON CODE'});
```

Comment: sorry did editing your code when im was going to edite mine sorry